# Why am I getting this error: unexpected '$' in "$"

Tags: r, latex

I have found similar questions to this on StackOverflow but none actually give a proper fix

The TA in my course was using this exact code and it was working. This is just the snippet but I keep getting the same problem. Anyone know why?

```
$n_{i}$
#Hint for Q1
$\hat{\beta_1}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_{i}-\bar{x})(y_{i}-\bar{y})} 
{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_{i}-\bar{x})^2}$
```

Then the Error is

```
Error: unexpected '$' in "$"
```

Maybe its because I'm running on Ubuntu?

Comment: That is Latex code so dont put it in an R code block. The TA was probably using a Sweave of Rmarkdown doc (but it still wouldn't be in a code block)

Comment: @user20650 Oh I see, what is a Sweave if you don't mind me asking? I'll look into it more but if theres a just quick high level explanation. I also just put it in the code block myself trying to get it to work

Comment: you can get a bit of info if you type `vignette("Sweave")` in the R terminal. But as you tagged Rstudio there is also https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552056-Using-Sweave-and-knitr

Comment: Alternatively use  package `rmarkdown` .  if you use RStudio "File > New File ? R Markdown " will generate a new `.Rmd` document . An internet search along the lines of  "rmarkdown latex inline math" should provide plenty of examples

Comment: Why were all references to rstudio or r edited out? In latex, only the unescaped # would be a problem, but this would be a totally different error. The information that the OP tried to use this in r and *not* in latex seems to be essential to understand the problem.